# Can't get one to one related objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have entities:

```
public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
        ...
public class Profile
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
```

When I try to get User I get error:

```
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Profile' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

When I change entities to:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
        ...
public class Profile
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
```

I get error:

```
{"Invalid column name 'Profile_UserId'."}
```

What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/ it could work:

```
public class User
{
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual User User { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Now I get `Invalid column name 'ProfileID'.` I updated question added my database diagram. Why you remove `UserId` from `Profile` and add `Id`?

Comment: I thought it's code-first approach. It will be harder with existing DB structure, but could you try setting `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` on Profile property (and rename your column to UserId as well)?

Comment: I tried that and I get: `One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

 System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'User_Profile_Source' in relationship 'User_Profile'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be �1�.`